# Can not be applied while setting adapter for RecyclerView in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

I am trying to implement RecyclerView in

> BottomSheetDialogFragment

but at time of setting

> adapter to recyclerView

, compile time error showing it can't be applied. Am I doing wrong using recyclerView in BottomSheetDialogFragment or is there any other way??

Comment: Your question not clear. please explain more

Comment: Can we use recyclerView in BottomSheetDialogFragment in android ??

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem.Actually It wasn't problem, it was my silly and poor mistake.. I was trying to set adapter on my BottomSheetDialogFragment class itself. Sorry for posting this type of silly problem..